# What is the best method to snap features to road network?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, network-analyst, snapping

I have a road network with some of my tract centroids and facilities that fall off of it, however I would like to execute my analyses so that all features are part of the road network?  My facilities are hospitals and incidents are census tract centroids.  I am executing a closest facility analysis for drive time and distance.  I would like my output to adjust these features to the network with an output in an attribute table which shows the distance the feature was adjusted to the network.  Much like the near analysis, but actually adjusting features so that they fall within the network.

Answer (score 1):

The result of your network analysis can be stored as a route event. You can then use "[locate feature along route](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003m00000007000000.htm)" to create a point event on your route. It will give you the distance.

Alternatively there is the [snap point](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/snappoints.htm) tool in GME (a free ArcGIS extension) that does it.